# How to use fetch() in react front-end to get data from express back-end?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to make a full-stack web-app using react and express. It's going pretty well atm but here's my problem:

So I have express running in back-end. All paths are used by react router except for '/api'. At the '/api/blogposts' path my server.js send the results of a query I made to the mySQL server. (I've checked it and this part works. If I browse to /api/blogposts my browser shows a json with the contents of my blogposts table).

My problem is with getting it to show in my react front-end. I'm trying to use fetch() but it doesn't work. Here's my code for the component that is supposed to fetch the blogposts:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Blogposts.css';
import SingleBpost from '../SingleBpost/SingleBpost.js';

class Blogposts extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            receivedPosts: []
        };
    }
    async getBpostsFromServer() {
            const response = await fetch("/api/blogposts");
            let myPosts = await response.json();
            this.setState({receivedPosts: myPosts});
        }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getBpostsFromServer();
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.receivedPosts);
        return(
            <div id="Blogposts">
            <SingleBpost title="OwO" date="18/12/2021" author="Kepos Team" body="Hello, this is a test for the blogposts!" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Blogposts;
```

Just to clarify the {this.state.generateBlogpost()} in the render method is just to check if I can get the data for now. Once this works I will feed it into another component's props like this:

```
<SingleBpost title={this.state.generateBlogpost().title} date={this.state.generateBlogpost().date} author={this.state.generateBlogpost().author} body={this.state.generateBlogpost().body} />
```

Anyways: does anyone know why this doesn't work? I've tried a few things but I just can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state of the variable `receivedPosts` in the fetch function like this :

```
this.setState({receivedPosts: results});
```

Also, you can call the function `generateBlogpost()` at the load of the Component `Blogposts` by adding the following function :

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.generateBlogpost();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I changed it to match what you said (haven't used react in a while totally forgot about setstate). Now it still doesn't work. When I console.log from my server.js it comes out fine but when I console.log from generateBlogpost() it returns undefined even though the console.log from the first callback from fetch() returns a 200 ok code.

Comment: Can you modify your code in the post, so we can see exactly what you have in your local environment ?

Comment: of course! I just edited it! :)

Comment: Maybe you can try to console.log(results.data); It depends on your API response format.

Comment: Hi!  I tried using async instead of .then() just to see and it has improved the situation but it still doesn't work. I updated my code in the post so what you see in the post is my current code. Now when I run this for some reason, even though there is only one console.log, there are two things logged to my console. The first thing is an array containing a bunch of stuff, the second thing is actually what I need. But setting my component props to the contents of the array still doesn't work. Here's a link with the contents of the first array I get: https://imgur.com/a/q40aVkq

Answer (score 0):

this one is useless

```
.then((results) => {
                this.state.receivedPosts = results;
            });
        return this.state.receivedPosts;
    }
```

//instead you should use setState({receivedPosts: data.data})

Comment: Yeah I totally forgot about setState (haven't used react in ages). Now I fixed this but it still doesn't work. Here's the response I sent to another commenter:


Thanks for the help! I changed it to match what you said (haven't used react in a while totally forgot about setstate). Now it still doesn't work. When I console.log from my server.js it comes out fine but when I console.log from generateBlogpost() it returns undefined even though the console.log from the first callback from fetch() returns a 200 ok code. 

Do you have any idea what's wrong?